# Deployment from NetBeans to Glassfish is very slow

Tags: performance, deployment, netbeans, glassfish-3

I have a project with a few dozen EJBs and a web project that I'm attempting to deploy from NetBeans 7.0.1 on my laptop directly to Glassfish 3.0.1 on a Solaris 10 server.  Ignoring the transfer time of copying the ear file, the deployments seem to take a very long time (3 minutes is the fastest I've seen it).  The performance of deployments seems to degrade over time, to the point where eventually I have to restart my domain.  I've seen a deployment take anywhere from 12-20 minutes after I've redeployed my application a few times.

I deploy by right-clicking my main project in NetBeans and picking "Deploy".  What options do I have for making this more usable?  What additional information can I provide to help track down the source of the problem?

UPDATE: Letting the most recent deployment run through to completion, it ended with the following error message in my log:

[#|2011-08-20T14:05:54.494-0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=2490;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
|#]

So this does appear to be memory related.  The deployment itself ran for over 10 minutes before dying in this manner.

Comment: If you use Visual VM to with the GF plugin to monitor the perm space do you see it getting larger?

Comment: I can't seem to get VisualVM to recognize my Glassfish instance, even with the plugin installed and active.  From watching the java process under top it has appeared that the memory consumption steadily grows over time, but I don't have any hard numbers to go against that right now.  I'll try stopping the domain and taking a baseline, then redeploying a few times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of my application's requirements, I had to increase the heap space from the default 512MB allocation to a min/max of 1GB/2GB.  This seems to have improved deployment slightly.  My typical deployment time is ~1 minute now.  It's not stellar, but it's at least tolerable.

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of a serious bug in the weld-integration module of Glassfish. Without this bug the deployment is more than 20!! times faster as before. 
http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18875

Please vote to get this fixed as soon as possible!